Sorting top 4 ranking by name
I am creating an automated scouting report for a basketball team. I am looking to automatically populate a list of team leaders in a variety of categories. In this case, I am looking at leading point scorers per game.
I have the raw data of who is scoring the most points per game, but I will like to automatically populate the Top 4 scorers and list their jersey number, name, and scoring average.
text
I don't quite know where to begin. I know how to use the rank function, but not to sort on another tab.
